# Collision Detection Java 2D Sprite

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection, sprite

So I'm trying to implement collision detection in my game and for some reason the collision isnt working properly.

```
public class ArenaKeys extends KeyAdapter {
    arenaScreenBuild arena;
    int xPos = 0, playerFace = 4;
    int xPPos = 200, yPPos = 150;
    int pX = 40, pY = 30;
    AttackAshe aAtk = new AttackAshe();

    int[][] mask = new int[400][92];

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();// Get key pressed
        if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
            playerFace = 4;
            xPos += 5;
            pX = (xPos + xPPos) / 5;
            if (checkBoundary(pX, pY) == (false))
                xPos -= 5;
        } else if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
            playerFace = 3;
            xPos -= 5;
            pX = (xPos + xPPos) / 5;
            if (checkBoundary(pX, pY) == (false))
                xPos += 5;
        } else if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
            playerFace = 2;
            yPPos -= 5;
            pY = yPPos / 5;
            if (checkBoundary(pX, pY) == (false))
                yPPos += 5;
        } else if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
            playerFace = 1;
            yPPos += 5;
            pY = yPPos / 5;
            if (checkBoundary(pX, pY) == (false))
                yPPos -= 5;
        }
        if (keyCode == e.VK_SPACE) {
            aAtk.regArrow(arena.xPosition(), arena.yPosition());
            arena.shoot(playerFace);
            arena.xArrow = xPPos;
            arena.yArrow = yPPos;
        } else if (keyCode == e.VK_ESCAPE)
            System.exit(0);
        arena.moveArena(xPos);
        arena.turnPlayer(playerFace);
        arena.updateScreen(xPPos, yPPos);
    }

    public boolean checkBoundary(int x, int y) {
        Rectangle t1 = new Rectangle(Turret.x, Turret.y, Turret.WIDTH,
                Turret.HEIGHT);
        Rectangle p = new Rectangle(pX, pY, Player.WIDTH, Player.HEIGHT);

        if (t1.intersects(p))
            // if (mask[x][y] == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    public static class Turret {
        static int x = 168;
        static int y = 40;
        static final int WIDTH = 50;
        static final int HEIGHT = 50;
    }

    public static class Player {
        static final int WIDTH = 25;
        static final int HEIGHT = 25;
    }

    public ArenaKeys(arenaScreenBuild arena) throws Exception {
        this.arena = arena;
    }
}
```

Approximately 20 units before the actual turret, the sprite stops being able to move any further. The sprite cannot go above or below the turret even if you go really high or really low.

What seems to be going wrong is that the sprite is colliding into the turret rectangle too early but I don't understand how that it possible. I draw the turret exactly 50 wide, 50 high at 168,40. The player is moving so it's x, y is different everytime but it's dimensions are 25 wide and 25 high.

[image: My Turret]

The original turret is 126x111 approximately but I draw it as 50x50

[image: Sample Sprite]
25x25

```
public class arenaScreenBuild extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    String picPath = "pictures/";
    String[] fileName = { "stageBridge.png", "turret.png", "Ashe.png",
            "regArrow.png", "arenaScreen.png" };
    ClassLoader cl = arenaScreenBuild.class.getClassLoader();
    URL imgURL[] = new URL[5];
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image imgBG, imgTurret, imgPlayer, imgRegArrow, imgBorder;
    Boolean[] ptFunc = new Boolean[3];

    int PLAYER_INITIAL_X = 200, PLAYER_INITIAL_Y = 150;
    int xPos = 0, xPFace = 150, yPFace = 0;
    int xPPos = 200, yPPos = 150;
    int xVal, yVal, xArrow, yArrow, xTemp, yTemp;
    Timer space;
    int counter, facePosition = 1;

    public arenaScreenBuild() throws Exception {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            imgURL[x] = cl.getResource(picPath + fileName[x]);
        }
        imgBG = tk.createImage(imgURL[0]);
        imgTurret = tk.createImage(imgURL[1]);
        imgPlayer = tk.createImage(imgURL[2]);
        imgRegArrow = tk.createImage(imgURL[3]);
        imgBorder = tk.createImage(imgURL[4]);
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            ptFunc[x] = true;

        space = new Timer(100, this);

    }

    public void updateScreen() {
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveArena(int x) {
        xPos = x;
    }

    public void updateScreen(int x, int y) {
        xPPos = x;
        yPPos = y;
        repaint();
    }

    public boolean arrow() {
        return (true);
    }

    public void turnPlayer(int face) {
        if (face == 4) {
            xPFace = 150;
        } else if (face == 3) {
            xPFace = 100;
        } else if (face == 2) {
            xPFace = 50;
        } else if (face == 1) {
            xPFace = 0;
        }
        if (yPFace == 50)
            yPFace = 0;
        else if (yPFace == 0)
            yPFace = 50;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(imgBG, 10, 30, 610, 490, xPos, 0, xPos + 600, 460, this);

        g.drawImage(imgTurret, 850 - xPos, 200, 950 - xPos, 300, 0, 0, 126,
                110, this);
        g.drawImage(imgTurret, 1350 - xPos, 200, 1450 - xPos, 300, 0, 0, 126,
                110, this);

        g.drawImage(imgPlayer, xPPos, yPPos, 50 + (xPPos),
                50 + (yPPos), xPFace, yPFace, xPFace + 50, yPFace + 50, this);

        if (counter <= 5000 && counter > 0)
            g.drawImage(imgRegArrow, xArrow, yArrow, this);

        g.drawImage(imgBorder, 0, 0, 620, 600, 0, 0, 620, 600, this);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("x:" + (xPPos + xPos), 535, 525);
        g.drawString("y:" + yPPos, 535, 545);
    }

    public int xPosition() {
        xVal = xPPos + xPos;
        return (xVal);
    }

    public int yPosition() {
        yVal = yPPos;
        return (yVal);
    }

    public void shoot(int i) {
        facePosition = i;
        xTemp = xPosition();
        yTemp = yPosition();
        space.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        counter++;

        if (facePosition == 4) {
            if (counter <= 5000) {
                xArrow += 50;
            }
        }

        else if (facePosition == 3) {
            if (counter <= 5000) {
                xArrow -= 50;
            }
        }

        else if (facePosition == 2) {
            if (counter <= 5000) {
                yArrow -= 50;
            }
        }

        else if (facePosition == 1) {
            if (counter <= 5000) {
                yArrow += 50;
            }
        }

        if (xArrow == (xTemp + 100)) {
            counter = 0;
            space.stop();
        }

        updateScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong? More specifically than "not working."

Comment: sorry i forgot to write that, updated the question.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to try a hard collision check, instead of using functions which are built into Java. This would be literally taking the size of the sprite, and checking if another sprite hits those bounds and overlaps with those pixels.

Comment: I can tell you the problem isn't with Java's `intersect` function. I've used it before and it's fine. My guess is that OP has mixed up the position and width/height somewhere. He says it's about 20px/units off and the player's width is 25px/units. That would be my guess. Can we see how you display those sprites? Maybe it's just a visual problem.

Comment: I meant the code where you actually draw the sprites. ;-)

Comment: @Exikle Do you still have the problem? If the problem has been fixed, don't forget to tell us what fixed it so it can help future users who search and find your post.

Comment: @mbinette sorry, it hasnt been fixed, i just went to sleep, that is why there was no reply, as to the code which i draw the sprites, i have added that into my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my values for the x position were wrong. Also due to my previous boundary code, there were still remenants of it which messed me up therefore not allowing me to see the problem sooner.

For any one looking for how to make the collision detection boundary, just make 2 rectangles and use the

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(topLeftX, topLeftY, rectangleWidth,rectangleHeight);
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(topLeftX, topLeftY, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight);
if (rect1.intersects(rect2))
//enter code to do if it intersects here
```

Comment: For anyone that asks me why i haven't accepted my own answer, i can't till 2 days are up

Comment: Also consider the `interects()` methods of classes implementing the [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface.